# Multiple services vs unique service

Tags: wcf, wcf-4

Hi i would like your help so i can decide on what to do with this matter. The thing is that at my work we are currently migrating from Web Services to using WCF, now the thing is that when we used web services we had one web service that was in charge of invoking the business logic now the thing is that i would like to know what is actually the best way to achieve the same functionallity with WCF, using one unique service to call the different business logic classes or have multiple services to call the different business logic classes? also i have to clarify that when i say one unique service i mean that this will have just one method that one way or another will be capable of invoking any of the business logic classes depending on certain parameters and will also have other methods but for other different tasks, now i would like to know which would be the best approach for this, by the way the reason we have consider using one service like i told you is to manage from there the commits or rollbacks necessaries when something blows when making an operation on the db and have it just from one place, not all over the place, thanks in advance and well i'm kind of new with wcf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can migrate your existing service structure into WCF and still have the same functionality.  You'll need to create and expose the service(s) according to WCF, but the architectural structure can remain how you have it in Web Services.  You may want to revisit your design.  There are many features at your disposal, including Entity Framework, that allow you to manage commits, rollbacks, etc.

Comment: thanks for your quick answer! and yeah, actually we are going to use Entity Framework and the goodies WCF has to offer but what we wanted is to keep some of the structure we already had you know, to keep it a little familiar but with this new technology.

Comment: Sure, use the latest technology, but also keep some familiarity.  You'll be fine migrating, but also take a look at re-factoring your service contracts earlier rather than later.  This will mitigate breaking changes, etc.